# Is the maximum of independent Poisson random variables log-concave?

Tags: pr.probability

Let $X_1,\ldots, X_n$ be independent Poisson random variables with parameter $\lambda > 0$. Define
$$M_n=\max \lbrace X_1.\ldots, X_n \rbrace,\,\,p_j=\mathbb{P}(M_n=j).$$
Is it the case that $M_n$ is log-concave, i.e., that $p^2_j\geq p_{j-1}p_{j+1}$?